# Ignore a higher kinded type parameter when extending a class

Tags: scala

Having following class

```
class Foo[F[_]]
```

I want to implement enrichment trait

```
trait EnrichedFoo extends Foo[_]
```

but this gives typing error:

```
error: _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: one
  trait EnrichedFoo extends Foo[_]
                                ^
```

Running example: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/CkMwDSi/0

Edit:

Why?  I want to have an enrichment that would work for any param value, so I can write something like this:

```
class MyFoo extends Foo[List] with EnrichedFoo
```

I have to extend `Foo` because I want to be able to override some of its methods, so `EnrichedFoo` cannot be a self type(if it helps anyhow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare the following:

```
trait Foo {
  type HK[F]
}

trait EnrichedFoo1 extends Foo {
  def enrich1 : Unit = ???
}
trait EnrichedFoo2 extends Foo {
  def enrich2 : Unit = ???
}

abstract class FooClass[HK0[_]] extends Foo {
  type HK[F] = HK0[F]
}
```

Then the user can do:

```
class MyFoo1 extends FooClass[List] with EnrichedFoo1
class MyFoo2 extends FooClass[List] with EnrichedFoo2
class MyFoo12 extends FooClass[List] with EnrichedFoo1 with EnrichedFoo2
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you be able to do that with higher-kinder parameters when you can't with the simple ones? If you have

```
class Bar[A] ...

class Baz extends Bar
```

it'll merely do normal type inference for `Bar`'s type parameter, so it's equivalent to `class Baz extends Bar[Nothing]`.

> I have to extend Foo because I want to be able to override some of its methods, so EnrichedFoo cannot be a self type(if it helps anyhow).

These methods can't mention `F`, or you couldn't even write down their signature in `EnrichedFoo`, right? Then why not split `Foo` into two parts:

```
trait FooBase {
  // methods not mentioning F
}

trait Foo[F[_]] extends FooBase {
  // other methods
}

trait ExtendedFoo extends FooBase { self: Foo[F] forSome { type F[_] } => 
  // method overrides
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're totally correct. I just haven't check if it works with simple type parameters first. And yes, methods I want to override doesnt need any information about `F`.

Comment: `forSome` might be dropped in dotty (Scala 3), https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped/existential-types.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass concrete class/trait in `Foo` with type constructor `* -> *` which means that it takes type and returns type, e.g. `List` which takes, let's say, `Int` as type parameter and returns type `List[Int]`.

```
class Foo[F[_]]
trait EnrichedFoo extends Foo[List]
```

Comment: Thats the point, I want to have an enrichment that would work for any param value. So I can write something like `class MyFoo extends Foo[List] with EnrichedFoo`

Comment: How about this?

`trait EnrichedFoo[F[_]] extends Foo[F]`
`class MyFoo extends Foo[List] with EnrichedFoo[List]`

Comment: Yes, this is an option but closer to a workaround than solution. I was looking for a way to ignore this parameter at all so the user doesn't have to specify it. But would do if there is no other option.

Comment: You can just write `class MyFoo extends EnrichedFoo[List]` instead of `Foo[List] with EnrichedFoo[List]`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice that misprint